# What song plays in Episode 902 in One Piece at 16:20?

Tags: music, one-piece

Can anyone tell me the name of the OST in Episode 902 at 16:20 when Luffy and Zoro fight against sumo wrestlers?

Answer (score 2):

The song is "Battle in the Colosseum" (コロシアムでの戦闘 ). It's track#21 from Album Original Soundtrack "New World", released on 2016-07-20

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9feq908XxTM